# Will core functionality in QGIS 3.0 exploit multi-threading?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, multithreading, qgis-3

As mentioned in a [recent QGIS blog by Tim Sutton](http://blog.qgis.org/2016/01/17/help-us-to-plan-for-qgis-3-0/), the major changes to QGIS 3.0 are:

- Updating Qt4 to Qt5
- Updating PyQt4 to PyQt5
- Updating Python 2.7 to Python 3
- Improving the QGIS API

Also, a couple of years ago, [Boundless](https://boundlessgeo.com/) seemed to have did some work on [multithreading the execution of various processing algorithms](https://boundlessgeo.com/2015/12/latest-developments-in-qgis-processing/) back in 2015:

> **Multithreading execution**. Multithreading execution of Processing algorithms was implemented as part of the Google Summer of Code this year. We collaborated in mentoring that work, but still some work has to be done before the code is ready to be merged. We have already started reviewing the code and adapting it with the goal of having this important functionality ready before QGIS 3.0 is released,, and we hope to have it ready for testing soon.

---

Will core functionality in QGIS 3.0 finally exploit multi-threading?